# What are the different types of callables in Python?

Tags: python, callable-object

I used to think `functions`, `classes`, and `methods` as the only callables in Python, but recently learnt that `instances` can also be made callable. This left me wondering if I'm done with this list or are there more types of callables I'm yet to encounter.

Comment: Any object that has `__call__` defined is a callable

Comment: Also, everything you've mentioned is callable via `__call__`: `types.FunctionType.__call__`, `type.__call__`, `types.MethodType.__call__` all exist.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the type of all *those* callables is `wrapper_descriptor` (certainly a CPython implementation detail), which would make that the only *ur*-callable type. (All other types being callable because they define `__call__`, not because they are somehow special-cased to be callable.)

Comment: Oops: there is also `method-wrapper` (another CPython implementation detail, the type of e.g. `id.__call__`. Circularity ensues when you ask about `id.__call__.__call__`, `id.__call__.__call__.__call__`, etc. It's `__call__`s all the way down.